# Combine this SQL update operation that deletes all unqualified items and enables all qualified items?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update, deadlock

I am performing the following intentions:

I have in my query a list/table of voucher_codes that are effectively qualified.
I want to mark all student_vouchers that are in this list as deleted = 0 and is_applied is marked true, if they appear in the list.

For all other student_vouchers under the given foreign key student_header_id of a student_header table that do not appear, i want to mark these as deleted with applied false.

The following code performs well enough, however I seem to be encountering plenty of deadlocks in regards to other transactions interacting with student_vouchers. So I think it would be better if I can merge this into a single update operation, is that possible? And would such change help fix the deadlock situation?

```
DECLARE @applied_voucher_table table
                                       (
            value nvarchar(max)
                                       );    
-- REMOVE INVALID STUDENT VOUCHERS
UPDATE student_vouchers
    SET is_applied   = 0,
        deleted      = 1,
        deleted_date = GETDATE(),
        edited_date = GETDATE()
    OUTPUT INSERTED.voucher_code INTO @DeletedVouchers
    WHERE student_header_id = @HEADERID AND deleted = 0;

DECLARE @AppliedVouchers TABLE (voucher_code NVARCHAR(MAX));
IF (
                (
                    SELECT COUNT(*)
                    FROM @applied_voucher_table
                    WHERE value IS NOT NULL
                    AND value != '') > 0
                )
BEGIN
                --UPDATE VALID VOUCHERS
    UPDATE student_vouchers
        SET is_applied   = 1,
            deleted      = 0,
            edited_date  = GETDATE(),
        OUTPUT INSERTED.voucher_code INTO @AppliedVouchers
        WHERE student_header_id = @HEADERID
          AND voucher_code IN
             (SELECT value
              FROM @applied_voucher_table
              WHERE value IS NOT NULL AND value != '')
          AND id IN (SELECT id
              FROM @applied_voucher_table);
 END;
```

```
student_vouchers (
  id,
  student_header_id,
  voucher_code,
  is_applied,
  deleted,
  deleted_date,
  edited_date
```

Let me know if there is something unclear!
Note that it is impotant that i receive this list @DeletedVouchers, however it would be good to also have the @AppliedVouchers list, which are both sent to a remote process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the two tables and updates into one, by using a left-join and some `CASE` or `IIF` expressions.

```sql
DECLARE @UpdatedVouchers TABLE (voucher_code NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, is_deleted bit NOT NULL);

UPDATE sv
SET is_applied   = IIF(avt.id IS NOT NULL, CAST(1 AS bit), CAST(0 AS bit)),
    deleted      = IIF(avt.id IS NOT NULL, CAST(0 AS bit), CAST(1 AS bit)),
    deleted_date = IIF(avt.id IS NOT NULL, sv.deleted_date, GETDATE())
    edited_date = GETDATE()
OUTPUT inserted.deleted, inserted.voucher_code
INTO @UpdatedVouchers (voucher_code, is_deleted)
FROM student_vouchers sv
LEFT JOIN @applied_voucher_table av
    ON avt.value = sv.voucher_code
   AND avt.value != ''
   AND avt.id = sv.id
WHERE sv.student_header_id = @HEADERID
  AND (sv.deleted = 0 OR avt.id IS NOT NULL);
```

Note that the semantic in the left-join is slightly different from the original, but I suspect this is more correct anyway. In the original, the `id` and `value` could be matched from different rows, where it looks like it should have been an `EXISTS` iwth two inner `WHERE` conditions. In this version, they needs to come from one row.